# Datepicker does not select any dates if instantiated after AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Found a peculiar bug indeed.

Datepicker works normally as expected until I load an object via AJAX and *then* attach the datepicker to it like so :

```
    $(".object").datepicker({
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonImage: '/images/icons/silk/calendar.png',
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    yearRange: "2010:2030"
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      console.log('this was tapped.');
      console.log(dateText);
      console.log(inst);
    }
    })
```

If I click on the input or icon, the datepicker pops up. But if I select anything, the datepicker closes, and the date in my input does not change.

**Update**

Even stranger. I updated with the `console.log` calls above, and they all return **properly**. Yet the date within my input does not change.

**Update**

I think what might be happening here is that there are several common divs on the page with the same unique ID since its a self clone-able form.

**Update**

Here is the bug recreated in JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vMhrg/

Comment: I don't think I follow... Can you post a jsfiddle displaying that issue?

Comment: Especially with the HTML in use. That's crucial, because, in your own words, "Datepicker works normally as expected".

Comment: Hmm.. I don't believe I'd be able to load a datepicker via AJAX with jsFiddle ( i could be completely wrong though ). Otherwise, I updated my question above to be a bit more clearer.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do that?

Comment: Wow! I reproduced it in JSfiddle. :) Link is above ^^

Comment: "there are several common divs on the page with the same unique ID since its a self clone-able form".  They're not *unique* then, are they? This very likely is your problem - you can't have multiple elements with the same ID...at least, not if you're interested in predictable behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with you having duplicate IDs.  ID *can not* be used more then once a page, consider adding a counter (as I do in the fixed code) or remove it entirely if you can.

http://jsfiddle.net/vMhrg/1/

Code (everything else is the same):

```
<input type="text" value="05/08/2012" size="10" rel="Recurring End Date" name="task[scheduled_at]" id="task_scheduled_at_1" class="date-single-view">

<br />
<br />
<div class="item">
<input type="text" value="05/08/2012" size="10" rel="Recurring End Date" name="task[scheduled_at]" id="task_scheduled_at_2" class="date-single-view">
</div>
```

​

Comment: Right, but the trouble is that will go to the server as `params[:task_scheduled_at_2]` which won't save anywhere.

Comment: Wowaweewah! Two datepickers work when I remove the Id's. Can anybody explain *why* ID's cannot be used in the DOM? I have two duplicate forms and jQuery/UI doesn't give errors... except for this.

Answer (score 1):

you're calling calling datepicker() on both .item and .date-single-view, which are nested elements in your dom (according to the fiddle, below), that's probably not a good idea - either call datepicker on a div **or** an input field, but not both.

```
<div class="item">
   <input type="text" value="05/08/2012" size="10" rel="Recurring End Date" name="task[scheduled_at]" id="task_scheduled_at" class="date-single-view">
...
```